# Looping Error in Console C++

Tags: c++

I am programming a console C++ shopping list program and I am getting this weird looping error when I attempt to delete an item from the shopping list. If the name of the item I am trying to delete is more than one word, it loops between the main menu end of this function extremely rapidly.

The code for the deleteItem function is as follows:

```
void deleteItem()
{
    string itemToDelete;
    cout << "Which item would you like to delete?" << endl;
    cin >> itemToDelete;

    iFile.open("ShoppingList.dat");
    if(!iFile.is_open()) //check that file exists
    {
        cout << "Shopping List doesn't exist! Returning to main menu." << endl;
        cin.get();
        mainMenu();
    }
    oFile.open("Transfers.dat", ios::trunc); //create and/or clear temp transfers.dat                             file
    oFile.close();
    while (!iFile.eof())
    {
        getline(iFile, newItem);
        if(newItem.compare(itemToDelete) != 0)
        {
            oFile.open("Transfers.dat", ios::app);
            oFile << newItem << endl;
            oFile.close();
        }
    }
    iFile.close();
    int result;
    remove("ShoppingList.dat"); //delete old ShoppingList.dat
    result=rename("Transfers.dat", "ShoppingList.dat"); //Rename the file with     transfered data to the Shoping List
    cout << "Success" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
    mainMenu();
}
```

All necessary variables for the function have been declared and all necessary headers have been included. This is not causing any compiler flags on Code::Blocks, but it is causing this strange looping when `itemToDelete` is longer than one word.

Comment: `cin` reads until a whitespace. Use `getline` if you want more than one word.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the most probable solution is that you meant to do:

```
getline( cin, itemToDelete );
```

If you use `cin >> itemToDelete` it will only read one word.  You haven't shown any of the logic outside of `deleteItem()` so it's hard to comment on what effect this will have.

However, I am curious about what the `mainMenu()` function does.  You seem to call it as if it's going to return from your `deleteItem()` function, which of course it doesn't.  Don't you mean `return`?

Comment: That's a good point. This looks like a stack overflow waiting to happen.

Comment: `mainMenu()` is actually the primary menu of the function. I just use it as a call back for when a function is finished. It isn't a return call because I don't always want it to return to the function where it was originally called (it may have gotten called from a separate function entirely).

Comment: That's cool, but please pay attention to the other part about calling `mainMenu()` from `deleteItem()`.  In particular, does `mainMenu()` call `deleteItem()`?  In that case, you will be winding your stack up every time.  You probably need to treat `deleteItem()` as an operation that knows nothing about the existence of a main menu.  Replace calls to `mainMenu()` with `return`.  Back to the original problem, I suspect your rapid-fire menu could be caused by using `cin.get()` in `mainMenu()`, so each character in the word left over in `cin` was interpreted as a (possibly invalid) menu choice.